# How can i set an onAreaTouched listener to a TiledSprite or ButtonSprite after initialized it?

Tags: android, button, sprite, andengine

i know i can set this listener initializing like this:

```
buttonSprite = new ButtonSprite(X, Y, mITextureRegion,
            mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {

                return true;
            }
            return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX,
                    pTouchAreaLocalY);
        }
    };
```

This works. But i want something like this:

```
buttonSprite = new ButtonSprite(X, Y, mITextureRegion,
            mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
```

first create it, and then set the onAreaTouched (i guess must be something like this, but doesn't work because not exists this setter)

```
buttonSprite.setOnAreaTouched(new onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
                float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {

                return true;
            }
            return super.onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX,
                    pTouchAreaLocalY);
        }
    };
```

And i don't find any mode to do it. it's possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can't, onAreaTouched is not an event, it's just a method in sprite class, which you can override in your subclasses (like the first example, which is an anonymus subclass).

However you can extend the sprite class, create an interface for events, add a list of it to the new sprite class and run it's method in onAreaTouched.